# How to fit content which goes past footer i.e. overflows using CSS and Div tags?

Tags: html, css

I have spent hours looking for a solution and cannot find anything on this particular issue, so please forgive me if it has been answered.

I have a standard CSS page with a masthead, a navigation row, a left column for links, a right column for contents and a footer.

I have set everything to the center of the page at 1024px wide.

What I just cannot achieve is to have the 2 columns stay at the same height when one has longer content than the other.

Let me explain this - both columns have a 1px border that I would like to extend all the way down to the footer. The right column has much longer content so it reaches the footer very quickly but the left column doesn't so the border stops, where the links finish.

To fix this problem I have set the heights to 100% in the html, body, container and the two columns as follows:

```
html {
height: 100%;
}

body {
height: 100%;
}

#masthead {
width: 1024px;
height:100px;
margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;
}

#top_nav {
width: 1024px;
height:100px;
margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;
}

#container {
width: 1024px;
height:100%;
margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;
}

#left_col {
width: 198px;
float: Left;
height: 100%;
border: 1px solid #FF0000;
}

#page_content {
margin-left: 200px;
width: 824px;
height: 100%;
border: 1px solid #000000;
}

#footer {
bottom: 0px;
clear: both;
width: 1024px;
height: 50px;
margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;
border: 1px solid #000060;
}
```

This works **BUT** now the content of the right column (which is much longer) goes way past the footer? and no matter what I try I cannot fix this without affecting the left column's border i.e. I can use **min-height: 100%;** which fixes the overflow and footer problem, BUT this has the side effect of capping the border on the left column back to the Navigation link's height i.e. so the border no longer flows to the bottom of the left column and down to the footer (grrrhhh!)

Here is a link to the page itself which you can copy and paste into DW or EW etc. to see what's going on:
http://www.iifuture.org/downloads/testzzz.html

If anyone knows how to fix this paradox I'd love to know about it!

Thanks
Shaun

Answer (score 0):

**Edit(revised answer after discussions)**

[This article](http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/developing_with_web_standards/csslayout/2-col/) helps.

```
style="background: blue url(someimage.png) repeat-y left;"
```

Add the above style to `container`. This is a hack, the DIV doesn't grow but the background image covers it up  to get the layout you want!

Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699257/css-height-100-problem) question and answer selected to learn more.

**Original answer**

Please take a look at overflow property. I was able to get your example page working with the below style added to page_content DIV.

```
position:absolute;overflow:auto;
```

With this code the scrollbars appear if the content exceed the height set. If you do not want to get the scrollbars and are okay with not showing the data beyond the DIV height, just use **hidden** instead of **auto**. Likewise, to display the scrollbars at all times, you may use **scroll**.

The last option **visible** will make it *(mis)*behave the way it is behaving right now i.e. letting the data grow beyond the DIV height. Notice that the DIV is not growing, only the content is.

Comment: Yes I know of this solution but I'd really like to avoid Scroll bars if at all possible... Another way is to just set a px height which also works but I have 700 pages which all vary in height so I was just going to use PHP and set them all as .inc files so I need a percentage solution - but I just can't seem to find one!!

Comment: I assumed that you wanted the container DIV height to be 100%. If you want the container to expand according to the content in left column and page content, as @Guy Fawkes mentioned, you can simply remove the 100% height on container DIV.

Comment: That's just not working at my end? I've tried so many combinations but no matter what I try I either get the border stopping at the contents of the Left Column or the text (content) of the right column flowing past the footer... if it's not too much trouble could you email the .css file (that you've modified to shaun@iifuture.com so I can see what on Earth it is I'm doing wrong? I nearly have no hair left!

Comment: @Shaun I'm using Chromium browser and I didn't create any file. I opened your test html and used built-in feature(I think it's called Developer Tools (ctrl+shift+j)). Open page -> right click on any div -> disable the height property of container DIV.

Comment: Yes I just did this in Chrome BUT - you will see the red Border (box) around the left Column now shrinks down to only go around the content and no longer flows to the footer (as it did) and there is the very problem - it's subtle but when you have lots of content the last thing you want is a blank area below your links...

Comment: @Shaun there is a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699257/css-height-100-problem). Check the links at the bottom of Step 6 on [this](http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/developing_with_web_standards/csslayout/2-col/) page. Don't forget to document how you solved it. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately none of these articles appear to deal with the situation I have where there are 2 columns that contain one short and one long div and how to overcome the overflow problem when one column goes way beyond the footer... because as soon as you set the min-height to 100% to overcome the footer issue i.e. the overflow no longer exists, the short column no long extends to the footer !
Even the repeating background trick doesn’t work!  I may be missing something but the tutorials don’t seem to account for this problem?

Comment: Okay I've tweaked the original file with the repeating background which clearly shows the problem... it's located at: http://www.iifuture.org/downloads/testzzz.html

Comment: Please remove the repeating background from left_col and add it to container. `style="background: blue url(images/testback.png) repeat-y left;"` should do the trick. Also, the height=100% might not be required on both right and left columns.  I wish you had looked at those articles a bit more carefully. Note that this fix doesn't account for the opposite case i.e. left col is longer than the right. I'm sure you can fix that.

Comment: @Lobo - thank you so much, this has corrected the problem and your assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: @Shaun You are welcome. If this answer solves your question, accept it using the little tick mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually scratch that : remove the `height:100%` on the container, left col and page content. That's it.

Comment: No the content still flows past the footer when I try this in all browsers?

Comment: @Shaun Try to just remove it on the #container. It's odd though cause when I try, for me it works in all browsers

Comment: Okay I've tweaked the original file with the repeating background which clearly shows the problem... it's located at: iifuture.org/downloads/testzzz.html