# Making columns extend the whole height of the page

Tags: html, css

I am having a heck of a time making the three columns (not the header or footer, but everything contained in the div with the classes colmask and threecol.

Any hints? The website is http://pacecarz.com/

I have made the body and html tags have 100% height. I have tried making the #wrapper div be height 100% and the colmask div height 100% as well, but this extends over the page (it would be correct if there were no header or footer though). Help would be appreciated.

Comment: You might wanna look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973962/how-to-fit-content-which-goes-past-footer-i-e-overflows-using-css-and-div-tags); the OP had similar page layout and height related problems.

Comment: You can always bite the bullet and use a table

Comment: @Sam and get your teeth blasted out ;)

Comment: @Blender - sometimes I'm amazed at the hoops people jump through to avoid using tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I messed around with @Blender's solution for a while and couldn't get it to do quite what I wanted. And so, I have gone with a different, similar solution that seems quite elegant to me.

http://brassblogs.com/blog/sticky-footer

Three columns, fluid center column, header, footer, all the features I needed. Woot!

Answer (score 2):

You are in need of a [Sticky Footer](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/). You won't be able to do much without it, have fun getting your site to span 100% height.

Basically, you layout your site like so:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <header>
    ...
  </header>

  <div id="main">
    ...
  </div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
  ...
</div>
```

And then include the [magical CSS](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/style.css). Tweak it to your needs, as it won't work out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 0):

A simple javascript answer would be (using jQuery):

```
var hdr_hght = $('#header').height();
var ftr_hght = $('#footer').height();
var set_height = function () {
  $('.colmask').css({ height: $(window).height - hdr_hght - ftr_hght});
}
$(window).resize(set_height);
set_height();
```

Ask if you would like a standard (non-jQuery) version.

Comment: CSS is more appropriate for layout than JS.

Comment: But there is no other way to properly do it.

Comment: Lemme make a pure-css solution. CSS is *made* for this ;)

Comment: Here you go, an almost-working solution. Too lazy to tweak, but a POC: http://fiddle.jshell.net/pB5Ur/7/show/

Answer (score 0):

You can also use something similar to [footerStickAlt](http://www.themaninblue.com/experiment/footerStickAlt/), which has HTML of this form:

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="nonFooter">
            <div id="content">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The applicable CSS is [explained by The Man in Blue](http://www.themaninblue.com/writing/perspective/2005/08/29/).